# Is there a way to Mock (using Moq ) a service within a service and execute the code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, moq

I have a testing question using Moq. I have looked everywhere but I don`t quite understand what's going on exactly.

I want to test a Class(service) which is called Basket, inside that class I pass as DI another Class(service) DiscountService.

The problem I'm facing is that whenever I mock the Basket class, it is well triggering, but when it reaches the code of actually executing another method inside the DiscountService, it just skips that method instead of going in. What I'm doing wrong?

I think it might be that I`m not doing a SETUP properly?

Here is my actual testing code so far:

```cs
 [Test]
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Test1Async()
        {
            //Arrange
            var basketServiceMock = new Mock<IBasket>();
            var discountServiceMock = new Mock<IDiscountService>();

            List<BasketProductModel> productsModel = 
                new List<BasketProductModel> 
                { 
                    new BasketProductModel()
                    {
                        ProductName = "Milk",
                        ProductPrice = 10,
                        Quantity = 3
                    }
                };
            BasketModel basket = new BasketModel { Products = productsModel };
            basketServiceMock.Setup(x => x.Baskett)
                .Returns(new BasketModel { Products = productsModel });

            var product = new BasketProductModel()
            {
                ProductName = "Milk",
                ProductPrice = 10,
                Quantity = 1
            };
            var product1 = new BasketProductModel()
            {
                ProductName = "Milk",
                ProductPrice = 10,
                Quantity = 1
            };
            var product2 = new BasketProductModel()
            {
                ProductName = "Milk",
                ProductPrice = 10,
                Quantity = 1
            };
            var product3 = new BasketProductModel()
            {
                ProductName = "Milk",
                ProductPrice = 10,
                Quantity = 1
            };

            discountServiceMock.Setup(x => x.ApplyDiscount(ref basket, product));
            var basketService = new Basket.Basket(discountServiceMock.Object);


            //Act
            await basketService.AddProductToBasket(product);
            await basketService.AddProductToBasket(product1);
            await basketService.AddProductToBasket(product2);
            await basketService.AddProductToBasket(product3);

            //Assert

        }
```

And this is my Basket class:

```cs
       public class Basket : IBasket
    {
        private BasketModel _basketProducts;
        private double _totalCost;
        public BasketModel Baskett { 
            get {
                if (_basketProducts == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("xxxxxxxxxx");

                return _basketProducts;
            } 
        }

        public double TotalCost
        {
            get
            {
                if (_totalCost == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("xxxxxxxxxx");
                }

                return _totalCost;
            }
        }

        private readonly IDiscountService _discountService;

        public Basket(IDiscountService discountService)
        {
            _discountService = discountService;

            _basketProducts = new BasketModel();
            _basketProducts.Products = new List<BasketProductModel>();
        }

        public async Task AddProductToBasket(BasketProductModel product)
        {
            if (product == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();


            var obj = _basketProducts.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductName == product.ProductName);
            if (obj == null)
                _basketProducts.Products.Add(product);
            else
            {
                obj.Quantity += product.Quantity;
            }
            _discountService.ApplyDiscount(ref _basketProducts, product); <---This part is being skipped, do I miss something in the SETUP part?!

        }


    }
```

And this is my DiscountService Class which is not triggered (ApplyDiscount method)

```cs
       public class DiscountService : IDiscountService
    {

        public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> discountedProducts = new List<String> {
                                                                                            "Milk",
                                                                                            "Butter",
                                                                                            "Bread",
        }.AsReadOnly();

        public void ApplyDiscount(ref BasketModel basket, BasketProductModel product)
        {
            if (discountedProducts.Contains(product.ProductName) && basket.Products.Count > 0)
                product.CalculateDiscount(basket);
        }

    }
```

This is the BasketProductModel ( Products inside the basket )

```cs
    public class BasketProductModel : DiscountProcess
    {
        public BasketProductModel()
        {
            Init(this);
        }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double ProductPrice { get; set; }
        public int Quantity;
        public int Freebies { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the Abstract class which is used in the above class, for using some pre-configured implementations

```cs
    public abstract class DiscountProcess
    {
        private BasketProductModel _obj { get; set; }
        public BasketProductModel Obj
        {
            get
            {    // check _obj is inited:
                if (_obj == null) throw new Exception();
                return _obj;
            }
        }

        protected void Init(BasketProductModel bPModel)
        {
            _obj = bPModel;
        }

        public void CalculateDiscount(BasketModel basket)
        {
            var productContained = NumberOfProductsInBasket(ref basket, _obj);
            var obj = basket.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductName == _obj.ProductName);

            var freeItems = 0;
            switch (_obj.ProductName)
            {
                case "Milk":
                    if (productContained % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        obj.Freebies = numberOfFreeItems(obj.Quantity);
                        //AddQuantity(ref obj);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Butter":

                    break;
                case "Bread":
                    productContained = NumberOfProductsInBasket(ref basket, productName: "Butter");
                    if (productContained % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        CalculateDiscountedPrice(50, ref obj);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            CalculateTotal(ref obj);
        }

        //...Other Methods...
    }
```

So basically I would like to be able to access even the code inside the service and execute all the code so that I can assert the Basket :)

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

End goal:

I would like the `Baskett` To have data based on what the DiscountService has done to the basked passed by ref so that I can assert in the end.

Comment: Why are both classes being injected into each other? (Circular dependency). Which one is suppose to be the subject under test?

Comment: @Nkosi good point, I`ve spotted it as well...and I`m planning to refactor it, However, the subject under test it supposed to be the basked, which inside we inject the discountService...(ignore the dependency inside the DiscountService which is the Basket)

Comment: @Nkosi I've updated the question with some new info + I refactored the circular dependency :) Would you mind having a look whenever you can please?

Comment: You're mocking the `DiscountService`... why on Earth would you expect that the actual service\'s methods would be called?

Comment: @IanKemp good question, that's why I guess I'm here, to learn from my mistake. I guess I didn't understand what's going on, so I wanted a bit of help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Basket` is the subject under test, then it should not be mocked.

```
//...

//Arrange
var basketServiceMock = new Mock<IBasket>(); //<-- Should not be mocked
var discountServiceMock = new Mock<IDiscountService>();

//...
```

Instead, use an actual instance,

```
var discountServiceMock = new Mock<IDiscountService>();
Basket basketServiceMock = new Basket(discountServiceMock .Object);

//...
```

and mock the dependencies required to exercise the test case to completion.

The subject in this case initializes a model in its constructor that you try to setup in the test. Since the model is being initialized by the subject class, then no need to try and create one in the test. Just populate it as needed for the test.

Review the following

```
[Test]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Test1Async() {
    //Arrange
    
    var discountServiceMock = new Mock<IDiscountService>();

    Basket subject = new Basket(discountServiceMock.Object);

    List<BasketProductModel> productsModel = new List<BasketProductModel> { 
        new BasketProductModel() {
            ProductName = "Milk",
            ProductPrice = 10,
            Quantity = 3
        }
    };
    subject.Baskett.Products =  productsModel; 
    
    // Only matches if the ref argument to the invocation is the same instance
    discountServiceMock
        .Setup(x => x.ApplyDiscount(ref subject.Baskett, It.IsAny<BasketProductModel>()));
        //You need to decide what you want the mocked member to do.
    
    var product = new BasketProductModel() {
        ProductName = "Milk",
        ProductPrice = 10,
        Quantity = 1
    };
    var product1 = new BasketProductModel() {
        ProductName = "Milk",
        ProductPrice = 10,
        Quantity = 1
    };
    var product2 = new BasketProductModel() {
        ProductName = "Milk",
        ProductPrice = 10,
        Quantity = 1
    };
    var product3 = new BasketProductModel() {
        ProductName = "Milk",
        ProductPrice = 10,
        Quantity = 1
    };

    //Act
    await subject.AddProductToBasket(product);
    await subject.AddProductToBasket(product1);
    await subject.AddProductToBasket(product2);
    await subject.AddProductToBasket(product3);

    //Assert
    //...You need to decide what it is you are actually testing
    //and want to assert

}
```

Observation:

The member under test is defined as `async` but nothing is actually awaited in the member. Recheck the design of that member.

Comment: thanks for this, I amended the async stuff as well, I await it. However, I still have the same issue, inside the class `Basket`, I have a method called `AddProductToBasket`, It goes in, but the problem is that if i try to go inside it and see what's going on there, it is not going in, it is skipped instead (goes to next line rather than debugging inside that method) `ApplyDiscount`. Any ideas how we can get inside the method to debug? :)

Comment: @CsibiNorbert put a break point in the `AddProductToBasket` method. When you try to step in it should hit the break point

Comment: I think you  miss understood what I said, the breakpoint hits inside the `AddProductToBasket`. However, when it reaches this method `_discountService.ApplyDiscount` and I try to get it, it doesn't get inside, which result in the `Baskett` not being updated with whatever the `ApplyDiscount` method is doing. :)

Comment: @CsibiNorbert oh Ok I see. There is nothing to go into. `ApplyDiscount ` is a mocked member. It is not the actual implementation. The dependency was mocked and injected into the subject under test.

Comment: so basically in order to test that, I should test that separately & not in this particular test..?

Comment: @CsibiNorbert that is correct. That would need it's own isolated unit test. using its actual implementation as the subject of the test.

Comment: Oh I see, it makes sense. And one last question, how do you achieve integration test? I will have to test the `ApplyDiscount` first, to make sure it does what it supposed to do, and then, once those tests are passing, I'll have to mock the `ApplyDiscount` method to return something and then assert whatever the `Basket` class does? I've changed the code slightly so that I dont pass by ref the basket object, instead I return it from `ApplyDiscount` method.

Comment: @CsibiNorbert for integration you would need both actual instance

Comment: okay, so in this case I'll create an instance of the DiscountService and pass it to the subject as you call it, right? :)

Comment: @CsibiNorbert yes that is correct in that case.